# replacing text in multiple elements in an XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

I have multiple endpoints in an XML doc where I am trying to replace some of the address strings. I don't want to replace the same text in the entire doc just in the endpoints. So I have tried to narrow it down and tried different ways but I cannot get it to work.

This is my most recent attempt. Am I missing something incredibly obvious here?

```
$xmlDoc = [XML](Get-Content "$path\filename.exe.config")

foreach ($i in $xmlDoc.configuration.'system.serviceModel'.client.endpoint) {
  if ($i.address -match "bla") {
    $i.address -replace "bla", "foo"
  }
}

$xmlDoc.Save("$path\filename.exe.config")
```

Comment: `-Replace` does not have side effects like changing value of left operand. It just return resulting value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @PetSerAl is trying to tell you is that the `-replace` operator doesn't update the `address` nodes. You need to assign the modified value back to the node to actually change your XML data. Also, depending on the structure of your XML, dot-notation may not work for you (if a parent node contains several address nodes, `$i` would contain a list of these nodes). I'd recommend using `SelectNodes()` with an XPath expression to be on the safe side.

```
foreach ($addr in $xmlDoc.SelectNodes('/configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint/address')) {
  $addr.'#text' = $addr.'#text' -replace 'bla', 'foo'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. 
It was unable to find #text however i tweaked what you supplied to      

foreach ($addr in xmlDoc.SelectNodes('/configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint')) {
$addr.address = $addr.address -replace 'bla',"foo"
}   

Which has done the job. 
Thanks again